# Video auto played in display none div

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, fancybox

I have vide an iframe with video that needs to be played in fancybox.
Here is the code:

```
<a id="playLink" href="#pageVideo">Link for video   </a>

    <div style="display:none">
      <div id="pageVideo">
       <iframe src="someVideo.mp4?autoplay=true" style="overflow:auto" frameborder="0" height="400" width="650"></iframe></div>
    </div>

$('#homePlayLink').fancybox({
    'padding' : 0,
    'width' : 560,
    'height' : 400        
});
```

The problem is that in Chrome video starts to play on page load. Because it is in display none div I do not see it but I hear the audio. How to fix this, so the video plays only in fancy box After click on the link?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your iframe src has the autoplay = true parameter; this is why it will auto play when the page loads.

How about pointing the iframe src to a blank page and then override the href when the fancybox opens?

```
$("#tip4").click(function() {
  $.fancybox({
        'padding'       : 0,
        'autoScale'     : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'title'         : this.title,
        'width'     : 680,
        'height'        : 495,
        'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
        'type'          : 'swf',
        'swf'           : {
             'wmode'        : 'transparent',
            'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
        }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Take a look at http://fancybox.net/blog  section 4: Show youtube clips.